# 19.04 / Virtual Box 6.08: manager screen fonts huge

Tags: virtualbox, mate

This is *not* an issue with the guest screen resolution, this is an issue with the manager main window opening on Ubuntu 19.04 MATE screen.

It is sized for what looks to be 640x480 -- on a 1920x1080 screen.

The Settings/Display dialog offers options for only the client displays.

The only likely setting I've found is in the `~/.config/VirtualBox/VirtualBox.xml` file :

```
  <ExtraDataItem name="GUI/LastWindowPosition" value="0,42,960,479,max"/>
```

But trying a number of different values for 'value', including blanks, has no effect.

It is interesting that 'Restoring' the window from `Maximized` before exit, removes the `max` value from the setting, so perhaps this setting *is* about the Manager window.

Deleting that file between invocations of VB has no effect.

There is a `virtualbox` file in `/etc/default` but there is no reference to display attributes in my version of that file.

I have posted this to the VirtualBox forum at Oracle.

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=93294

Resolved through [19.04 MATE and QT : oversized display, low resolution](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1154398/19-04-mate-and-qt-oversized-display-low-resolution/1160877#1160877)

Comment: Perhaps worth a try to close VBox, move the config file: `mv ~/.config/VirtualBoxVirtualBox.xml ~/.config/VirtualBoxVirtualBox.xml_bak` and then restart VBox. Should force a return to defaults, if not rename the _bak file to its original name...

Comment: @andrew.46 Liked that thought but -- no. So I tried a few reasonable values and some unreasonable values for the LastWindowPosition, but there was no change.

Comment: You may find that they prefer you to not edit this file directly, but with any luck you will get an answer as well :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This turns out to be a QT issue resolved by setting this environment variable:

```
QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1
```

Put it to `.bashrc` and all is well.