# 19.04 MATE and QT : oversized display, low resolution

Tags: nvidia, 19.04, mate, qt

MATE 19.04.

I have two QT applications -- VirtualBox Manager and QT pass. These applications display in very low resolution on one of my machines. The VBox Manager fills the screen so that the dialog controls are buried under the desktop's bottom panel.

Is there a QT tweak I can apply?

This is an issue on only one of my 19.04 machines. It is the only machine I have that uses NVIDIA however switching to the Nouveau driver doesn't fix the problem.

Comment: Only those 2 apps?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia As far as I can tell with `apt list --installed | grep -i qt` these are the only two QT applications I have installed. Many `qtlib` and so on but I don't see any otherI recognize as  applications.  Can you recommend a small and simple other I could try?

Comment: My question was regarding the problem, whether it hapoens only with thise apps? And am I correct assuming  you have the correct Nvidia driver installed? And the resolution set to the monitor's native resolution?

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia Ah. Yes. It is only these two apps. I mention QT because it is one thing they have in common that other applications do not share. I understand that does not conclusively point to QT as the cause of the issue.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia I missed half your question. Both the Nvidia and Nouveau drivers are correct according to the 'Additional Drivers' dialog. Monitor resolution is standard for both devices (laptop display and external monitor) on which the issue occurs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by adding the following to my .bashrc

```
QT_SCALE_FACTOR=1
```